# Add column vector to a dataframe of different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dataset

I have a time series, we can call D1, with 63000 rows and 2 columns:

```
        Time        pH
0          1  5.818488
1          2  5.821478
2          3  5.817494
3          4  5.816903
4          5  5.817778
...      ...       ...
63895  63896  5.759683
63896  63897  5.762894
63897  63898  5.759819
63898  63899  5.765182
63899  63900  5.764498
```

And I have a column vector, we can call D2, of 1050 rows:

```
      Bit
0       1
1       0
2       1
3       0
4       0
...   ...
1045    0
1046    0
1047    0
1048    0
1049    0
```

I want to add the Bit column of D2 to D1 in this way: first value of D2 assigned to first 60 rows of D1, second value of D2 assigned to rows 61-120, and so on:

```
        Time        pH        Bit
0          1  5.818488          1
1          2  5.821478          1
2          3  5.817494          1
3          4  5.816903          1
4          5  5.817778          1
...      ...       ...
63895  63896  5.759683          0
63896  63897  5.762894          0
63897  63898  5.759819          0
63898  63899  5.765182          0
63899  63900  5.764498          0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example,  `np.repeat()` does what you need

```
D2 = np.array([1,2])
np.repeat(D2,60)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that repeat function. It worked